# Does it make sense to use 'untenable' in this context?'

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I'm writing about a character who is facing an arranged marriage. Does it make sense to say that, in a situation such as this, developing feelings for someone else is 'untenable'? Are there any other adjectives that would be better suited for the following sentence?

"She needed to put aside these foolish feelings, which were simply (insert adjective) given her approaching nuptials.

Thanks

Comment: I'm hearing *wrong*, *upsetting*, *distracting*, *unwelcome*, *irrelevant*, or *unhelpful*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm writing about a character who is facing an arranged marriage. Does it make sense to say that, in a situation such as this, developing feelings for someone else is 'untenable'? Are there any other adjectives that would be better suited for the following sentence?

A woman in that situation may have many feelings generated by her attraction to one other than the one to whom she is betrothed. She may be trying to fulfill her role, finding her feelings untenable, silly, inappropriate, frustrating. Maybe she will break off the betrothal; maybe her feelings foretell an affair or family situation yet to come. Perhaps her love for her betrothed will grow.

It’s your story, she’s you character. so where you want this to lead is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

*Untenable* is usually used of an opinion or point of view rather  than an inappropriate emotion. You might use *out of the question,* or look up its synonyms.